# Configure authentication in azure appservice

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

how can I configure session lifetime in azure app service authentication to azure ad? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#extend-session-token-expiration-grace-period the authenticated session expires after 8 hours, but I want shorten it to one hour. What's more after one hour I want to force user to reenter credentials to given provider. By default after session is expired user is redirected to provider, but doesn't have to reenter credentials and immediately redirected back to app - even when I manually delete cookies from browser - how is that working without cookies? What's more in azure documentation I found description of token lifecycle management feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) which also have default id token's lifetime of 1 hour, which is very different from app service session lifetime, but redirected user to azure ad doesn't have to enter credentials even after manually deleting cookies. How is it working and how to configure that?

Comment: Probably due some form of Single sign on - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on, like IWA.

Comment: Hi, If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark the answer by clicking the arrow and verify by clicking the emoji below. Doing so helps others find answers to their related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Even the default token lifetime has a certain value as per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties), the [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens) allows an application to obtain a new access token without prompting the user.

> Single Sign On (SSO) occurs when a user logs in to one application and
>   is then signed in to other applications automatically, regardless of
>   the platform, technology, or domain the user is using. The user signs
>   in only one time hence the naming of the feature (Single Sign On).

Due to single Sign On(SSO) feature you are not able to enter credentils and directly able to login.